# Name for the elements *not* fixed by a permutation?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, terminology

Does anyone know if there is a standard name for the set of elements not fixed by a permutation? That is to say, if $\pi\in S_X$ the symmetric group on set $X$, then I am looking for a name/notation regarding $\{x\in X\mid\pi(x)\neq x\}$.

Comment: This set is usually called the support of $\pi$.

Comment: @Mark Thank you!

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the word support [usually means something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) for functions which are not permutations... instead meaning $\{x\in X~|~f(x)\neq 0\}$.  You can of course relate the two by letting $f(x)=(\pi(x)-x)$.  So, if you ever feel like your audience might think of this meaning of support instead then go ahead and use a few extra words to clarify what you mean.

Comment: @JMoravitz Indeed! I'm also using support to mean $\{x\in X\mid f(x)$ is defined$\}$, but I suspect that there won't be any confusion over the matter.

Comment: @CalliopeRyan-Smith That would be the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) (or rather the intersection of $X$ and the domain of $f$), absolutely not the same thing as what JMoravitz was referring.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut True. I should have clarified that I am using it in the sense of forcing, where calling the domain of a partial function the support is very much the convention.

Comment: @CalliopeRyan-Smith Thanks for the clarification, I didn't know this usage (and I confess I know nothing about forcing). So there are (at least) three definitions for the term depending on the context.